# How to prove that there is a step function in plane that converge to a Lebesgue integrable function in integral method

Tags: real-analysis

$f (s, t)$ is a Lebesgue integrable function in a finite rectangle $[a,b]\times[a,b]$. Prove that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there is a step function $ \varphi $ that meets
$$\int_a^b \int_a^b |\mathit f -\varphi|d\mathit x d\mathit y <\varepsilon$$

Here is my thought

Prove that there is a continuous function that meets the conditions, because  continuous functions can be converged to by step functions.

According to Fubini Theorem, $g(y)=\int_a^b \mathit f(\mathit x,\mathit y)d\mathit x$ is a Lebesgue function. Therefore, for any $\varepsilon>0$, there is a continuous function $\mathit h$ that meets $ \int_a^b |\mathit g -\mathit h|d\mathit y <\varepsilon$.

However, I got some troubles in pushing forward. Could you give me some hints? I will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

A cheating way is this:

Approximate the integrable function $f$ by a continuous function $\varphi$, and treat the integral of $\varphi$ as a Riemann integration in issue, and we know that the Riemann sum is of a type of step function, and the Riemann sums approximate $\varphi$.

For a type of Riemann sum $s=\displaystyle\sum f(c_{i,j})|Q_{i,j}|$, then $s=\displaystyle\int\sum f(c_{i,j})\chi_{Q_{i,j}}$, where $\chi_{Q_{i,j}}$ is the characteristic/indicator function of $Q_{i,j}$, so Riemann sum corresponds a step function and vice versa.

To be more precise, let $f(c_{i,j})=\max_{Q_{i,j}}f$, then $s=\displaystyle\sum f(c_{i,j})\chi_{Q_{i,j}}\geq f$ and hence $\|s-f\|_{L^{1}}=\displaystyle\int|s-f|=\int(s-f)=\sum f(c_{i,j})|Q_{i,j}|-\int f$ which is small.